# How to navigate the Infragistics' WebDataGrid control in the back end looking for the values of an UnboundCheckBoxField column?

Tags: vb.net, webforms, infragistics, webdatagrid

This is a fragment of my WebDataGrid:

```xml
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid1" runat="server" >
    <Columns>
        <ig:UnboundCheckBoxField Key="SelectedId" >
        </ig:UnboundCheckBoxField>
    </Columns>
</ig:WebDataGrid>
```

In the postback I want to iterate all the SelectedId column checking what was checked.
I was suggested the following code:

```vb
For Each row As WebDataGridRow In WebDataGrid1.Rows
        Dim checkBox As WebDataGridCell = TryCast(row.Items.FindItemByKey("SelectedId"), WebDataGridCell)

        If checkBox IsNot Nothing AndAlso checkBox.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            Dim checkBoxControl As CheckBox = TryCast(checkBox.Controls(0), CheckBox)

            If checkBoxControl IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim isChecked As Boolean = checkBoxControl.Checked
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

The problem is the compiler says the types **WebDataGridRow** and **WebDataGridCell** are not defined, at least with my version of Infragistics **(Infragistics45.Web.v21.2, Version=21.2.20212.9)**
Am I missing something?

Removing the types I tried:

```vb
For Each row In WebDataGrid1.Rows
    Dim checkBox = row.Items.FindItemByKey("SelectedID")
    ...
Next
```

The row variant happen to be of the **Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.GridRecord** type. And the checkBox variant is a **Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.GridRecordItem** type.
But no property looks to point to the checkbox. (The **checkBox** doesn't has the **Controls** property)

How to access the value of the checkbox at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely the suggested code is wrong: the types **WebDataGridRow** and **WebDataGridCell** never existed. The code that works is the following:

```
Dim result As String = ""
For Each row In WebDataGrid1.Rows
    Dim cell As GridRecordItem = row.Items.FindItemByKey("ChkSelectedID")

    If cell IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim value = cell.Value
        Dim isChecked As Boolean = value
        result &= IIf(isChecked, "1", "0")
    Else
        result &= "-"
    End If
Next
```

And another important point: run this code in the WebDataGrid.PreRender event. Before that it will return all the checkboxes as unchecked.